# ¿«¡Aflojá!» «Aflojále/Bajále un cacho al trago» es lo mismo que decir «No le des tanto al trago» en Argentina y Uruguay?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, coloquialismos, argentina, uruguay

En Argentina y Uruguay, ¿*¡Aflojá!* o *Aflojále/Bajále un cacho* es lo mismo que decir alguna de estas cosas?

- «No rayes con»
- «No te metas tanto+sust
- No le des tanto a+actividad
- No le des tanto al trago/a la bebida

Comment: No entiendo muy bien el sentido de esta pregunta. Por un lado solicitas que se validen posibles traducciones al inglés y por otro que se validen expresiones equivalentes en español. ¿Te has fijado en cuantas preguntas diferentes se agrupan en tu texto de arriba? Lo normal y aceptado es una pregunta por post. Si te fijas la etiqueta "traducción" está asociada a traducciones al español, desde otro idioma al español y no a la inversa. Y ese "le" entre paréntesis en "para decir que (le) tomara", para mí sobra completamente.

Comment: Disculpa, creo que me entusiasme con el tema, con "aflojále un cacho" que encontré pienso que tengo mi pregunta en español resuelta y en inglés ya alguien me confirmo mis dudas. Me cuesta enormemente escribirlo sin esos 'le', de verdad, pero no quiero confundir a nadie, por eso las (). Mejor ciérrenlo. Tengo que darme el tiempo de leer las reglas.

Comment: @RubioRic Me retracto: Lo escuché cuando alguien (le) decía en broma a otro: ¡Aflojá! para decir que tomara o bebiera con más calma.<-Tienes razón el segundo 'le' es totalmente innecesario, fue un error al editar.

Comment: Nada, hombre, no son necesarias disculpas ni retractaciones. Quizás me quedó el comentario algo borde, no era mi intención.

Comment: Un apunte ortográfico: debería ser "aflojale", "bajale". Desde la revisión de las normas de acentuación de 1999, las formas verbales con pronombre enclítico pierden la tilde si la combinación completa pasa a ser llana. Hasta 1999, se escribía "déme", "estáte", sentóse". Pero desde entonces, la RAE prescribe las formas "deme", "estate", "sentose". Esto es también aplicable a las formas imperativas propias del voseo, como "sentate vos". Véase https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/tilde-en-las-formas-verbales-con-pronombres-atonos-deme-estate-mirandolo-etc

Answer (score 0):

En parte sí. La primera no la conozco con ese sentido. La segunda no puedo decir que está mal pero es rara, la veo con falta de estilo. Las últimas dos tranquilamente son equivalentes.